# Search in array DNS entry

Tags: php, arrays

I have seen so many answers but i just can't get it to work.

I want to check if there is a (partial) value in the array.

```
//Get DNS records
$result = dns_get_record("php.net", DNS_ALL);
print_r($result);

//If the value php-smtp3.php.net is found, echo it

if (in_array("php-smtp3.php.net", $result   )) {
echo "Found!";
}
```

**added** : json_encoded $result, from my network

```
    [
        {
            "host"  : "php.net" ,
            "class" : "IN" ,
            "ttl"   : 375 ,
            "type"  : "A" ,
            "ip"    : "208.43.231.9"
        } ,
        {
            "host"   : "php.net" ,
            "class"  : "IN" ,
            "ttl"    : 375 ,
            "type"   : "NS" ,
            "target" : "dns2.easydns.net"
        } 
    ]
```

---

Thank you all so much, i think i am almost there and sorry if i dont understand fully. This is what i have now:

```
$result = dns_get_record("php.net", DNS_ALL);
print_r($result);

$result = json_decode($result, true);
$result = array_filter($result, function($x) {
return in_array("smtp", $x, true);
    //If in the array, no matter where, is "smtp" then echo "found" is what i am trying to achieve
    echo "<h1>FOUND</h1>";
});
```

Update:

```
 $result = dns_get_record("php.net", DNS_ALL);
 $result = json_decode($data, true);


 function process($data) {
     foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
         if (is_array($value)) {
             return process($value);
         }
         if (is_string($value) && strpos($value,'smtp') !== false) {
             echo "FOUND";
             return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
 }
 $result = array_filter($result, 'process');
```

I am trying both ways... so sorry you guys, i am stuck trying to get a response from the DNS entry for a simple string. The actual idea behind this is:

1) Check a DNS record for a domain
2) Check if there is a SPF record ANYWHERE
3) If so, just say "found SPF record"

```
 $values = array_reduce(
   dns_get_record("php.net", DNS_ALL),
   function ($out, $item) {
     return array_merge($out, array_values($item));
   },
   []
 );
 var_dump(in_array("dns2.easydns.net", $values));

 //Result is bool(true)
```

Comment: Show `print_r($result);`

Comment: In which field the `php-smtp3.php.net` should be? `target`?

Comment: @Rayalist Did any of the answers work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not, i keep getting stuck on the example i updated in the openingpost.

Answer (score 0):

After using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), your data returns a multi dimensional array where some arrays also contain an array.

What you might do if you want to check for a partial value so if the string contains a substring is to use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) but you have to loop throug all the strings, also in the sub arrays.

Therefore you might use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) in combination with a recursive approach.

So for example if you want to look for the substring `smtp3` you could use:

```
function process($data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            return process($value);
        }
        if (is_string($value) && strpos($value,'smtp3') !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
$result = array_filter($result, 'process');

print_r($result);
```

See the [php demo](https://3v4l.org/KNkBE)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to flatten the result and search for a value, like this:

```
<?php

$values = array_reduce(
  dns_get_record("php.net", DNS_ALL),
  function ($out, $item) {
    return array_merge($out, array_values($item));
  },
  []
);
var_dump(in_array("dns2.easydns.net", $values));
```